# Brown spot on fiddle leaf fig

Tags: figs

I have some brown spots on my fiddle leaf fig.
I have some large patches of brown spot on the big leave.
And some small patches on the new leaves.

May I know what could have caused the problem?
Should I cut the leave away?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ouchy — That looks very much like sunburn! A thing I notice in the first pic: see how there is less brown on the understory leaf; and only on it’s edge? Looks as though the leaf above it provided some sun protection for part of the day.

Try pulling this guy into a bit more of a bit more shaded position.